# IntelliJ Idea, “Not valid Scala home” error on Windows

Tags: scala, ide, intellij-idea

Alright, so I have Scala 2.10 installed on my computer, and it works fine in eclipse...

I recently installed IntelliJ Idea to see how good an alternative it was, but apparently it doesn't like my scala installation, it works fine on my macbook, but here it just says "not valid Scala home" despite the fact that it is the correct directory...

Upon creating a project and writing a bit of test code, I try to compile it, and in the debug console it says: "Error: scala: No compiler library set in module untitled1"

so what should I do?

Scala IS installed, but the IDE refuses to recognize its existance

Every time I've *tried* to use Idea, *something* always goes wrong

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

any help?

Edit: Changing the directory to `C:\Program Files (x86)\scala` produces the following error:

[image]

note that Scala DOES work in Eclipse

Edit2: Going through with the other change, still makes the IDE unable to recognize the compiler

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. *Path problem*. IntelliJ Scala plugin looks for installed distribution by first checking SCALA_HOME environment variable. If it is not set it will then scan folders from PATH environment variable. In the latter case it will ignore the fact that it found binary directory and not actual Scala home (so it will not adjust for added bin at the end of the path). Note that Windows Scala msi installer does not set SCALA_HOME (as it is not needed for Scala to function correctly). So you either **set SCALA_HOME environment variable** or navigate to that directory (as you did in your second screenshot).
2. *Sources problem*. Scala msi installer does not install source jars by default. Again as with SCALA_HOME variable they are not strictly needed. But to avoid manually setting compiler jar and also aesthetically displeasing error in your second screenshot :-) just **check "Sources" in setup options** screen.
3. *Scaladoc problem*. It was not part of the question but for completeness: scala api docs will be installed by msi installer (if you did not uncheck "API Documentation" in setup options). However they are in the "wrong" path from scala plugin perspective: `[SCALA_HOME]\doc\api`. It wants them instead in: `[SCALA_HOME]\doc\scala-devel-docs\api`. You can deal with it in variety of ways but I feel the most efficient one is to create a directory junction if you are on Windows 7. Go into elevated command prompt, change directory to [SCALA_HOME]\doc and run `mklink /j scala-devel-docs .` thereby redirecting scala-devel-docs to parent doc folder. Obviously msi uninstall will not remove it so you will have to clean it up if you ever uninstall scala.

Comment: This solution worked for me (Windows 8). I re-did the msi installer, added source, and pointed IntelliJ's Scala home to "C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\".

Comment: Adding "source" during scala installation worked for me.. thanks

Comment: what did it for me was to set `SCALA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\scala`

Answer (score 11):

Change the Scala home directory to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\scala
```

since that is the home directory. The `bin` directory is just one of many directories that belongs to the scala installation.

Comment: edits have been made to the original post to accommodate your suggestion.

Comment: @Electric That's just missing source jars. That shouldn't stop it from working. Try to build now, it really should work.

Comment: nope still can't compile the error says "no compiler library set in module <modulename>"

Comment: You also have to point out the compiler jar in the box under the red exclamation mark.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee No normally you shouldn't have to add it. It will be added automatically as soon as you point out the scala home directory. So what does your `C:\Program Files (x86)\scala` look like? Does it have a normal scala structure? Anyhow if you explicitly point out the scala compiler it should work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30226/discussion-between-electric-coffee-and-maba)

Answer (score 7):

Adding to what Keith Pinson says above ...

I had a similar problem today and eventually got it working after reading this [link](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5487092):

> Actually, Scala Facet configuration and general Scala plugin configuration are not simple for newbies, and this is big usability problem, which we have to fix. So your problems are understandable.

Hopefully these notes below will help you get going until someone more knowledgeable can confirm whether this is a bug or a usability issue.

After creating a new project I opened the Project Structures dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), moved to the "Libraries" tab, made sure there was a library created with a non-blank name, e.g. "Scala Library" then manually added these jars from the Scala lib directory:

```
scala-compiler.jar
scala-library.jar
scala-reflect.jar
scala-actors.jar
```

I then associated this library with my project on the Modules tab of the project properties.

Since then I've not had any trouble.

One more thing, this probably makes no difference, but my Scala installation is at:

```
C:\scala
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: what should I do if the libraries ARE under a blank name?

Comment: If I recall, I just renamed the library on the library tab.

Comment: ok so I also had to make the reference under the Facets tab and tell the project that I was using that library as my compiler... but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This problem is easily fixed , download the zip version from this link

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.10.2.zip

after that download the API docs if you needed, from this link

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-docs-2.10.2.zip

extract first "**scala-2.10.2.zip**", and after that extract the content of "**scala-docs-2.10.2.zip**" in a folder named "**api**", then copy the "**api**" folder to a dir like
this ***C:....\scala-2.10.2\doc\scala-devel-docs\api***

and thats all

sorry with my english... :)

Answer (score 0):

Something to try:

- Verify Scala path is correct -- open cmd and type "scala", it should start REPL
- In IntelliJ open Project Structure and set Global libraries for scala-compiler and scala-library
- Use the Existent Library option when creating an IntelliJ project

Comment: scala path is correct, project structure doesn't even give me the ability to add stuff, and the last opition didn't do anything either

Comment: In the New Project dialog, if I click "Set Scala Home" then I get the same error message as you.  But if I click "Extistent Library" the Scala libraries are there and it works.  I don't remember clicking on that "Download Scala" button it looks tempting.

Comment: trust me when I say it, both those drop-down menus in the "existent library" part are empty, completely empty

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post on here because I had the same issue and I found a simple solution.

This issue is being caused by using the MSI installer version of Scala. IntelliJ IDEA works much better with the .zip distribution of Scala.

- Go to http://www.scala-lang.org/download/ and click `All Downloads`
- Click on a version. I used the latest stable version 2.10.2 (http://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.10.2.html)
- Click on the .zip Windows package (http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.10.2.zip)
- Extract this zip to some directory. I used `c:\scala`
- Load up IntelliJ IDEA. Set the `Scala Home` path to `c:\scala\bin`
- Presto.

Answer (score 0):

When installing the windows version, also install the sources - then it works a lot better. It still complains a bit.